# How to change the default title in ngCordova dialogs?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Running `$cordovaDialogs.confirm('Coming soon...', 'Upcomming feature', 'Ok');` I get an alert with title `Index.html` in iOS, but with the right message.

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

My dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "cordova": "^6.2.0",
    "ionic": "^1.7.16",
  },
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs"
  ],
```

Comment: Be aware that the third parameter passed to `$cordovaDialogs.confirm` should be an `Array`. E.g. `$cordovaDialogs.confirm( 'Coming soon...', 'Upcomming feature', [ 'Ok' ] );` Probably this solves already your problem...

Answer (score 0):

The `$cordovaDialogs` is an Angular wrapper for the Cordova plugin for Native Dialogs and falls back onto the regular `alert()` function if it cannot find or access the Cordova plugin.

I think that your problem may be related to the plugin not being installed plugin. Could you try `navigator.notification.confirm` instead of `$cordovaDialogs.confirm`? And make sure that the plugin is installed by checking `cordova plugins` and using `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs` or `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs` if it is not (do not use both, only use `ionic plugin add` or `cordova plugin add`).